# custom sort in javascript

Tags: javascript, sorting

I'm trying to implement a custom `sort` function. I have these rules:

`['B', 'A'] => will become ['A', 'B']`

`['2', '1'] => will become ['1', '2']`

`['Down', 'Up'] => will become ['Up', 'Down']`

So if there are numbers or strings I want to sort them in ascended order, but if i have the keywords `Up/Down`, I want `Up` first, then `Down`.

Here is what I've tried so far:

```js
let c = [
  {
    pos: 'Down',
  },
  {
    pos: 'Up',
  },
];

c.sort(function (a, b) {
  console.log(a.pos) // why is this 'Up' and not 'Down'?
  if (a.pos === 'Down' && b.pos === 'Up') {
    console.log('enter on 1');
    return 1;
  } else {
    if (a.pos > b.pos) {
      console.log('enter on 2');
      return 1;
    }
  }
  console.log('enter on 3');
  return -1;
});

console.log(c); // expected result [{pos: 'Up'}, {'pos': 'Down'}]
```

I was expecting my code to `enter on 1` but it enters on `enter on 2` instead. So why if I `console.log(a.pos)` I obtain `Up` and not `Down`?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: There's no guarantee how the `.sort()` internal code will call your comparison functions. In other words, `a` and `b` are not necessarily the first and second elements of the array.

Comment: Should 'Up' and 'Down' be before anything else?

Comment: All you know is that `a` and `b` are two elements from somewhere in the array.

Comment: On my side, your snippet says: enter on 1 (clicked several times just in case)

Comment: @iota I will never have more than 2 values at the time. So either [A, B], either [1, 2], either [Up, Down]

Comment: So just check whether [0] == "Down"? In that case: swap. Using `.sort()` for a pair may be overdoing it when you have such particular rules.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but did you mean when there are words you want to go Descending order?

Comment: What if you have ["Up", "Right"] or ["Down", "Right"]?

Comment: @NeerajKumar not any `words`, only these 2: `Up` and `Down`

Comment: Does this have only two words?

Comment: @Neeraj, this is already answered above.

Comment: @Tenzolinho If there are only 2 values and you have specific set of rules, you might not need `.sort()` here. Agreeing with @trincot comments.

Comment: Running this script in firefox gives the expected result, btw. Which supports Pointy's words: don't expect any particular order of elements or invocations in the comparator. You get two elements and you need to return a zero, a positive or a negative number.

Comment: Alright, I understand now. Thank you all for your answers! ^^

Answer (score 0):

```js
function mySort(arr) {
  arr.sort(function (a, b) {
    a = a.pos;
    b = b.pos;
    if (a==='up' && b==='down')
        return -1;
    if (b==='up' && a==='down')
        return 1;
    if (!(isNaN(a)))
        return a-b;
    return a.localeCompare(b);
  });
  return arr;
}

console.log(mySort([{pos:'Down'}, {pos:'Up'}]));
console.log(mySort([{pos:'B'},{pos:'X'},{pos:'A'}]));
console.log(mySort([{pos:12},{pos:56},{pos:2},{pos:0}]));
```